# ntpdate take long time to sync (not ntpd)

Tags: ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

**I have referred [ntpdate -d Server dropped Strata too high](https://serverfault.com/questions/277375/ntpdate-d-server-dropped-strata-too-high). This is a similar but different question.**

I having two devices.

1. Freescale ARM board (NTP server)
2. Tinker board (client)

In the Freescale board which already installed an NTP server and the `ntp.conf` as below:

```
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 8
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

Then the client didn't installed the `NTP` server, only use `ntpdate` to sync with server once.

Here is the problem:

1. start the Freescale board NTP server `$ ntpd`.
2. sync in client `$ sudo ntpdate -u -d 192.168.1.10`
3. got error `192.168.1.10: Server dropped: strata too high`
4. Wait a few minutes...
5. sync again `$ sudo ntpdate -u -d 192.168.1.10`
6. this time no error

Once I `$ killall ntpd` and restart `$ ntpd` in the server, the client needs to wait a long time then`$ sudo ntpdate`.

For my understanding, `ntpdate` is used to force sync the time. Why takes so much delay time? And the error `strata too high` doesn't relate to the time at all.

Answer (score 1):

`ntpdate` does not sync the time, it steps the time once. [It also will be retired in favor of `ntpd` and `sntp` commands.](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) Do not use it on the client. Instead, configure a full NTP implementation like ntpd or chrony.

[Undisciplined Local Clock](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/UndisciplinedLocalClock), `LCL` refid and configured as a server matching CIDR 127.127.1.0/24, should not be used by anyone. Per NTP wiki:

> The Undisciplined Local Clock should generally no longer be used.
>
> It was originally designed to be used when an ntpd must be able to
>   serve time to others even when no real time sources are reachable.
>   Please see the Distribution Documentation for information about other
>   applications for the Undisciplined Local Clock.
>
> Users of ntp-4.2.2 and later should consider OrphanMode as a means of
>   keeping an isolated group of servers synchronized.
>
> The Undisciplined Local Clock is not a back-up for leaf-node
>   (i.e. client only) ntpd instance.

On the server, replace the server line with better reference clocks: NTP over the Internet, a time appliance with a radio, or a good oscillator.

If you must run a configuration without reliable reference clocks, use [orphan mode](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/OrphanMode). Set a stratum threshold lower than the fudged `LCL` you have configured on the network, but higher than a decent Internet source, typically 1 to 3.

```
tos orphan 6
```